# List of media files with its duration

Tags: video, terminal, ffmpeg, time, media

I wanted to get a list of mp4 files and its corresponding duration from all the folders matching the pattern below

e.g: LO1/LO1.MP4,LO3/LO3.MP4

I tried following but I get multiple entries as well as I cant figure out the filename:

```
$ mediainfo /var/www/videos/L*/L*.mp4 | grep Duration
Duration                                 : 25mn 54s
Duration                                 : 25mn 54s
Material_Duration                        : 1554665
Duration                                 : 25mn 54s
Material_Duration                        : 1554688
Duration                                 : 37mn 21s
Duration                                 : 37mn 21s
Material_Duration                        : 2241664
Duration                                 : 37mn 21s
Material_Duration                        : 2241696
Duration                                 : 26mn 6s
Duration                                 : 26mn 6s
Duration                                 : 26mn 6s
Duration                                 : 30mn 41s
Duration                                 : 30mn 41s
Duration                                 : 30mn 41s
Duration                                 : 39mn 41s
Duration                                 : 39mn 41s
Duration                                 : 39mn 41s
Duration_LastFrame                       : -7ms
Duration                                 : 37mn 2s
Duration                                 : 37mn 2s
Duration                                 : 37mn 2s
Duration_LastFrame                       : -12ms
Duration                                 : 34mn 24s
Duration                                 : 34mn 24s
Duration                                 : 34mn 24s
Duration                                 : 31mn 7s
Duration                                 : 31mn 7s
Duration                                 : 31mn 7s
Duration                                 : 31mn 57s
Duration                                 : 31mn 57s
Duration                                 : 31mn 57s
Duration                                 : 29mn 30s
Duration                                 : 29mn 30s
Duration                                 : 29mn 30s
Duration                                 : 36mn 28s
Duration                                 : 36mn 28s
Duration                                 : 36mn 27s
Material_Duration                        : 2187988
```

So how can I get a list of filenames(.mp4) and its corresponding duration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the output from mediainfo, but this is how I do it
using ffrobe (or ffmpeg -i) this will get the duration

```
ffprobe $fn 2>&1|grep Duration|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'|cut -d" " -f2|cut -d. -f1
```

using find will obtain the file names for you

```
find /var/www/videos/L* -type f -name L\*.mp4
```

so you can pop the whole lot together in a little for loop to get your list

```
for fn in `find /var/www/videos/L* -type f -name L\*.mp4`;
do
    dur=`ffprobe $fn 2>&1|grep Duration|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'|cut -d" " -f2|cut -d. -f1`
    echo "$fn $dur"
done
```

Comment: I prefer the `-exec` flag of find for this type of task because they save a lot of process forks: `find [filter rules] -exec mediainfo \{\} + | grep [filter]` or if you dont have GNU find `find [filter rules] -print0 | xargs -0 mediainfo | grep [filter]`.